# Minimising distance from origin to surface

Tags: geometry, optimization, surfaces

I am trying to minimise the distance from the origin to the surface $3x^2+\sqrt{3}y^2-\sqrt{3}z^2=1$.

I tried using this constraint and writing $z^2=\sqrt{3}x^2+y^2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, and then substituting this into $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

This gives a new function to minimise, $f(x,y)=\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{3})x^2+2y^2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}$.

But this function can equal zero for some values of $x$ and $y$ (I checked on Desmos too) and I know that no points on the surface have a distance from the origin equal to zero. Where have I gone wrong?

I've looked at similar questions and it looks like there's another way of answering questions like this using Lagrange multipliers, but I am not familiar with those and I think there should be a way to make this method work, but I can't figure out what mistake I've made.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes $f(x,y)$ is zero for some $(x,y)$, but are those $(x,y)$ permissible? Remember that you have the constraint $\sqrt{3}x^2 +y^2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}= z^2 \ge 0$

Comment: OK, I see that we need $\sqrt{3}x^2+y^2\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, but how do I use this to find the answer? Can I say that $f(x,y) \ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: Wolfram plot says the functionis  one sheet hyperboloid. in xy plane the equation is $3x^2+\sqrt3 y^2=1$ which is an ellise, x=0.6 is where it intersect x axis. In xz plane the equation is $3x^2-\sqrt 3 z^2=1$ which is a hyperbola , x=0.6 is intersection with x axis. In yz plane the equation is $\sqrt 3 y^2-\sqrt 3 z^2=1$ which is a hyperbola , x=0.6 is intersection with x axis . The value 0.6 is common in three planes, so it may be the minimum distane. One way is you find the distance separately  and find what you find using these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the constraint as
$$x^2 = \left( 1 - \sqrt{3}y^2 + \sqrt{3} z^3\right) / 3$$
You want to find a point on the curve with minimal norm. So we are minimizing norm, but we might as well minimize the square of the norm, to get rid of the square root in the norm. So, the problem you want to solve is
$$\min_{x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \quad \text{ s.t. } \quad 3x^2 + \sqrt{3} y^2 -\sqrt{3} z^2 = 1.$$
Now we perform the above substitution of $x^2$ in the objective function. Implicitly, this places a constraint on the values of $y$ and $z$, namely
$$\sqrt{3}y^2  - \sqrt{3}z^2 = 1 - 3x^2 \leq 1.$$
Hence, after substitution, the problem you are left with is
$$\min \left( 1 - \sqrt{3}y^2 + \sqrt{3} z^3\right) / 3 + y^2 + z^2 \quad \text{ s.t. } \quad \sqrt{3} y^2 - \sqrt{3} z^2 \leq 1.$$
Note that the objective function is convex (verify this yourself), so if we can find a stationairy point (all derivatives equal $0$) that is feasible, we have solved the problem. It turns out (check the details yourself) that the stationairy point $(y,z) = (0,0)$ is feasible, so this is the global minimum! Solving for $x$ gives $x = \pm 1 /\sqrt{3}$, and hence
$$(x,y,z) = ( \pm 1/\sqrt{3},0,0)$$
are the two points on the curve with minimal norm.

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your answer, I tried substituting expressions for $x^2$ (like you did) and $y^2$ too to see if they gave different results and yes it looks like $x^2$ gives a function that can be minimised. My question is why does substituting $z^2$ not work? How would you know which variable to eliminate without trying all of them?

Comment: If you substitute $z^2$, you get the implicit constraint $3x^2 + \sqrt{3} y^2 = 1 + \sqrt{3}z^2 \geq 1$. Your function $f^2$ has as stationairy point $(x,y) = (0,0)$, but this does not satisfy the previous constraint. Therefore, $f$ has a minimum on the boundary of the constraint somewhere, but finding this is clearly more complicated than the approach of substituting $x$ or $y$.

Comment: OK thanks so much I understand now!